# What is the best way to convert primitive types in XAML UWP?

Tags: wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, typeconverter

In `WPF`, `Silverlight` or `Windows Phone Silverlight` we had a nice way to convert to any type from a string which is specified in XAML.

The only thing we had to do is to subclass from `TypeConverter` and then mark particular properties or classes with `TypeConverterAttribure` specifying which converter the framework should use.

This feature is totally missing in `Universal App XAML` and the worst of all `Universal App XAML` has a very limited ability for value conversion.

You can use only `bool`, `int`, `double`, `string` and that's about it. If you create a custom control with dependency property of types `char` or `long` you cannot assign those properties in `XAML`.

The compiler says that it cannot convert from `string` to `char` for example. 
What would be the best work around if you need to assign control's properties in `XAML` for types like `char`?

So far I came up with an idea to use `{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource PropertyConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value}` where basically the Value is converted to the target property type with the help of `PropertyConverter` which simply calls `Convert.ChangeType` inside.

The problem is that this approach does not work in `XAMLs` which are in Themes directory, which are basically control templates. It works only for UserControls.

Is there a better way, ideally a universal way, to convert any type from `string` to a particular type when assigning in `XAML`?

Answer (score 0):

The Converter is the right approach. The reason why you cant use `x:Bind` in your theme xaml file (e.g inside datatemplace) is it require difference setup. You can use `Binding` in place of `x:Bind`.

sample:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsMenuOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Binding. As I mentioned I convert static data. x:Bind allows you to omit specifying a property name for binding. If you do it for Binding it simply does not invoke the converter.

Comment: How about use a property to return the static data and use Binding ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like starting in the Creator's Update you can now use [this method](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2017/02/15/implement-type-converter-uwp-winrt-windows-10-xaml.aspx) to replicate this behavior, from the article:

```
namespace CustomControlWithType
{
    [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.CreateFromString(MethodName = "CustomControlWithType.Location.ConvertToLatLong")]
    public class Location
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Altitude { get; set; }

        public static Location ConvertToLatLong(string rawString)
        {
            string[] coords = rawString.Split(',');

            var position = new Location();
            position.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(coords[0]);
            position.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(coords[1]);

            if (coords.Length > 2)
            {
                position.Altitude = Convert.ToDouble(coords[2]);
            }

            return position;
        }
    }
}
```